# Prevent incorrect formatting before jCarousel is initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

We just started using jCarousel with our application and we're experiencing some strange UI behavior. For a split second before the page is rendered, every LI that makes up the content is shown expanded on the page. Once the jQuery("#carousel-name").jcarousel(); is executed, though, the page springs back to what it's supposed to look like.

I assume that the reason we're seeing this in our app but not on any of the examples is because our content is a lot more complex than that of the examples on the jCarousel site and it takes longer for browsers to render the HTML.

I read elsewhere on Stack Overflow that hiding the divs in each li doesn't seem to work correctly because jCarousel can't figure out the proper width.

Before I try the headache of letting jCarousel dynamically load the carousel items, I'd like to see if anyone else has had this problem and if there are any easier solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by loading the content for the carousel inside hidden LIs at the bottom of the page. When the page loads, I initialize the carousel with an itemLoadCallback set:

```
itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: switchHiddenCarouselParts}
```

In the itemLoadCallback function, I add each hidden pane to the carousel:

```
carouselLoaded = false;
function switchHiddenCarouselParts(carousel, state) {
   if (!carouselLoaded) {
      panes = ["pane1", "pane2"];

      for (i = 0; i < panes.length; i++) {
         hidden = $("#"+panes[i]);
         carousel.add((i+1), hidden.html());
         hidden.remove();
         $("#"+panes[i]).show();
      }
      carouselLoaded = true;
   }
}
```